# how to change the string values of sting.xml file

Tags: android, textview, nullpointerexception

i hava a layout file like
test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/test_string" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and java file like this.
test1.java

```
public class test1 extends Activity {
String temp="This is String"; //which change dynamically
TextView tempview;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tempview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.test_string);
    tempview.setText(temp);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    }
}
```

what i am trying to do is show the value of temp in activity as above code. but it throws an `NullPointerException`. so how to do. how to set the values of sting.xml???
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

`setContentView(R.layout.test);` should come before `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.test_string);`

Comment: thanks for replying.. i have done as you suggested. it doesnot throw the nullpointer exception. But it does not show the value of temp in activity

Comment: You can add android:text="This is a String" as a parameter of textView in test.xml

Comment: Thanks for replying. If i add a parameter android:text="This is a String", then it will be static. But i need to change the text dynamically. how can i do this? plz help me sort this out.

Comment: I missed that in your comment, maybe you open a new question for that, or see if there is already an answer, so this question thread won't become a mess?